# oscommerce tep_db_perform -- update

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update, oscommerce

I am working on the simple function which update the value in database,
I am strange that when I add more than 1 where clause, the query didnot work.

I have worked on it over 6 hours already.
Please help

the first query work:

```
 tep_db_perform(TABLE_CUSTOMERS_EDUCATIONS, $sql_data_array, 'update', "customers_id = '" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'] . "'");
```

This query did not work:

```
 tep_db_perform(TABLE_CUSTOMERS_EDUCATIONS, $sql_data_array, 'update', "customers_id = '" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'] . "'" . " and seq_no = '" . (int)$education_seq . "'");
```

Seems there are not much discussion on this silly problem, but unluckily I am facing on this.
I know this may be a simple question but I am very new in php so please help me.
Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

your `$sql_data_array` should be correct.

```
$sql_data_array = array('customers_id' => (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'],
                        'seq_no' => (int)$education_seq
                        );

tep_db_perform(TABLE_CUSTOMERS_EDUCATIONS, $sql_data_array, 'update', "customers_id = '" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'] ."' and seq_no = '" . (int)$education_seq . "'");
```

Comment: if my answer is working for you then mark it as correct to help other people facing same issue. glad to help.